# Run Azure pipline with Selenium tests in Docker

Tags: azure, docker, selenium, docker-compose

I need to create a pipeline in Azure with my autotests using Docker container. I made it successfully on my local machine using the following algorithm:

1. Create Selenium node with next command:

   ```
   docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome:4.0.0-beta-1-20210215
   ```
2. Build image using command: docker build -t my_tests .
   next
   Here is my dockerfile:

   FROM maven:onbuild

   COPY src /home/bns_bdd_automation/src
   COPY pom.xml /home/bns_bdd_automation
   COPY .gitignore /home/bns_bdd_automation

   CMD mvn -f /home/bns_bdd_automation/pom.xml clean test

Everything works fine, but locally.
In the cloud I faced an issue: I need to RUN Selenium Node at first, and after that build my image.
As I understood from some articles I need to use docker-compose (for run first image), but I don't know how. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444

  bns_bdd_automation:
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
      - chrome
    build: .
```

But it works not as I expected. It builds and RUN tests BEFORE hub and chrome was executed. And after that it shows me in terminal:

```
WARNING: Image for service bns_bdd_automation was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
    Starting selenium-hub ... done
    Starting bns_bdd_automation_chrome_1 ... done
    Recreating bns_bdd_automation_bns_bdd_automation_1 ... error
    
    ERROR: for bns_bdd_automation_bns_bdd_automation_1  no such image: sha256:e5cd6f2618fd9ee29d5ebfe610acd48aff7582e91211bf61689f5161fbb5f889: No such image: sha256:e5cd6f2618fd9ee29d5ebfe610acd48aff7582e91211bf61689f5161fbb5f889
    
    ERROR: for bns_bdd_automation  no such image: sha256:e5cd6f2618fd9ee29d5ebfe610acd48aff7582e91211bf61689f5161fbb5f889: No such image: sha256:e5cd6f2618fd9ee29d5ebfe610acd48aff7582e91211bf61689f5161fbb5f889
    ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.
    
    Continue with the new image? [yN]
```